# click() in cell should not trigger click() in row

Tags: angular, angular-material

Given a Angular Material table. Each row shows a name and a link, both in its own cells. I want to call the function `rowFunction` whenever somebody clicks anywhere on the row, and call the `linkFunction` whenever somebody clicks the link.

My current solution is the following.
The problem is, that clicking on the link will call both the `rowFunction` and the `linkFunction`. But I only want to call the `linkFunction`, not both at the same time.

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="link">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Link</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <a (click)="linkFunction(row)">Link</a>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
     (click)="rowFunction(row)"></tr>
</table>
```

Link to codesandbox.io: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-cookies-qf3bo?file=/src/app/table.component.html

How can I avoid the click to the row, when I click the actual link in the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the click event to your `linkFunction` and call [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

The template:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
  <a (click)="linkFunction($event, row)">{{row.link}}</a>
</td>
```

The function:

```
linkFunction(evt, row): void {
  console.log("called link function");
  evt.stopPropagation();
}
```

[Here's a stackblitz demonstrating](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ow7gzi?file=src/app/table/table.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

I have to handle this as well.  I have to support the user being able to select a row as well as to click a link in the row without selecting the row.

I'm handling it like this (the switch statement lists every tag that appears in my rows that I want to treat like a select target)  :

```
public RowClicked(event: any) {
    switch (event.target.nodeName) {
        case "TD":
        case "PROPERTY":
        case "DIV":
        case "SPAN":
        case "P":
            //handle the actual row selection
            break;
    }
}
```

The tr has a click event like this:

```
(click)="RowClicked($event)"
```

Since A isnt in that switch statement, the row select callback isn't called.